# Format HTML lost Drives

Tags: html, powershell

I am working on a script to receive disk space alerts. Basically I calculate the units that are below 10% of space and I create an .html with the name of the server and the calculation of 10%.

```
Param([string]$ComputerName = "")

$disks = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $ComputerName -Filter "DriveType = 3 and DeviceID != 'C:'" | Where-Object {($.freespace/$.size) -le '0.1'} foreach ($disk in $disks) {

[PSCustomObject]@{
    Server = $ComputerName
    Drive = $disk.Caption
    AmpliarGB = [System.Math]::Round(($disk.Size / 1GB) * (10 /100) - ($disk.FreeSpace / 1GB) +40)
  
    } | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header | Out-File  "C:\temp\test.html"
    }
```

The server has 8 drives but when I run the script it only shows me one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Param([string]$ComputerName = "")

Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $ComputerName -Filter "DriveType = 3 and DeviceID != 'C:'" |
            Where-Object {($_.freespace/$_.size) -le 0.1} | 
                ForEach-Object {
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Server = $ComputerName
                        Drive = $_.Caption
                        AmpliarGB = [Math]::Round(($disk.Size / 1GB) * (10 /100) - ($_.FreeSpace / 1GB) +40)
                    }
                } | ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header | Out-File  "C:\temp\test.html"
```

Comment: My gosh. So fast and works fine!! Thank you so much man. I forget ForEach-Object :)